# Forward stepwise regression of log-linear model based on likelihood ratio

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glm

I want to perform some stepwise regression (possibly both forward and backward) in R for a log-linear model obtained using glm(), based on LogLikelihood ratio.

Ideally I am looking for a function similar to step() that doesn't use the AIC but the Loglikelihood ratio.

```
model<-glm(Frequency~ x+s+d+i, data=table_ll, poisson(link=log))
model_sat<-glm(Frequency~ x*s*d*i, data=table_ll, poisson(link=log))
step(model, scope=list(lower=model, upper=model_sat), direction="forward")
```

Thanks!
c

Comment: Statisticians tell us that stepwise regression is ["generally bad"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/how-to-do-logistic-regression-subset-selection/8312#8312). However, if you are set on this path [bestglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bestglm/index.html) might be of interest to you. Note that AIC is calculated from loglikelihood.

Comment: thanks @Roland! I will look into this. This is a starting point, having a 5-dimension contingency table with a lot of factors. Yup, AIC is based on LL but I wanted a direct comparison between the two LLs.I will def look into other methods as well. cheers!c